# Can I search a slice of a string in Python but keep the index relative to the original string?

Tags: python, regex, string, standard-library

I have a large string. I regularly have to search only parts of this string, but I do need to now where in the large string the bits found in the slices are found.

Is there a way to use a 'mask' on a string? That is

```
original = 'This is a mock-up large string'
a_slice = original[10:23]
a_slice.find('o')  
>>> 1 in a_slice; 11 in original
```

Simply repeating the search is no option as that is too CPU costly.

## Update

The toy example above uses find. In practice I use re.finditer().

Comment: Why don't you save the initial value in a variable and then add it to the index that you calculate from the substring?

Comment: I have thousands of slices so it might induce overhead, but it is worth the try, @BhargavRao.

Comment: The update shows that you are struck on an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also see [How much change to the question is too much?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like requested, if you want to use finditer (which returns an iterator of Match-objects):

```
>>> import re
>>> original = 'This is a mock-up large string'
>>> p = re.compile('o')
>>> for match in p.finditer(original, 10, 23):
...  print match.pos
10
```

Just a short note: finditer() function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) is not the same as finditer() method on a regex object (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.finditer)

Answer (score 7):

`str.find` takes option arguments as to where to start/end the search, eg:

```
original = 'This is a mock-up large string'
o = original.find('o', 10, 23)
# 11
```

From the docs:

> find(...)
>
> ```
> S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
>
> Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
> such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
> arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
> ```

Comment: O that is nice. I don't actually use find; do you know on the top of your head whether the regex finditer has the same?

Comment: yes finditer takes pos and endpos https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.finditer

Comment: @sphere can you put an example in an answer?

Comment: @Private so you've effectively just changed the question. That's not how SO works...

Comment: @JonClements not really, the update expands the scope, but does not change the essential question about masking (which by the way you do not answer). No offence intended

Comment: @Private the answer answers the question in the title, is inline with your example that you're trying to emulate, and I'm not sure you're sure what you mean by "mask". Anyway - expanding the scope is still changing the question. If you asked "How do I accept online payments using a credit card - here's an example", then said - "oh great, but I'm not really doing that, I'm really trying to use PayPal instead..." - it's a bit disingenuous...

Comment: fair enough;I agree;  is it worthwhile in this case to raise a new question? because in practice my question has been solved with your answer and sphere's comment?

Comment: I also agree that the question changed (find() vs finditer()). I added the requested answer though ;)